# Why flutter is unable to send data using POST method to django rest api?

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework

This is my part of code in auth.dart:

```
Future<void> signup(String username,String email, String password) async {
      final url =
        'https://ymukeshyadavmrj.pythonanywhere.com/register/';
    try {
      final jb = jsonEncode({
          'username': username,
          'email':email,
          'password':password,
          'password2':password,
      });
      print(jb);
      final response = await http.post(url,body:jb);
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData.containsKey('code')) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['message']['message']);
      }
      _token = responseData['access'];
      print("Token =======$_token");
      _refreshToken = responseData['refresh'];
```

It is returning null on printing **_token** after assigning it **responseData['access']**.

Note: I am using jwt authentication for my project and api is working fine in Postman.

Comment: Print the ```response.body``` and check the data.

Comment: It was helpful. This error was printing: "detail: Unsupported media type "text/plain; charset=utf-8" in request." Resolved by adding content-type in headers.

Answer (score 1):

**Only mistake in the code was that I was not using content-type in headers.**

Comment: what content type did you end up using? I've tried adding the following but it now just turns POST into OPTIONS on the django side
{
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
  }

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this, it should be a URI

```
final url = Uri.parse('https://ymukeshyadavmrj.pythonanywhere.com/register/');
```

Comment: But he wouldn't be able to run the code if ```post``` required a URI.